# silex root folder files unable to access from url

Tags: php, routes, silex

I have a website using Silex.

I have uploaded few files in root folder like `robots.txt` and few push notifications `sdk`.

Problem is getting error when I am trying to access that file using url :
`domain.com/robots.txt` is giving error when trying to access from chrome browsers

No route found for `GET /robot.txt`

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>    'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException' with
>    message 'Unable to generate a URL for the named route "" as such route
>    does not exist.' in
>    /home/path/domain.com/vendor/symfony/routing/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.php:134
>    Stack trace: #0
>    /home/path/domain.com/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/RoutingExtension.php(45):
>    Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator->generate(NULL, NULL,
>    false) #1
>    /home/path/domain.com/data/twig/fe/bb/cd3e9843c1ef02ee591d59cfb1afd51eb5cd52af42e38573c035f7ef4128.php(146):
>    Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension->getPath(NULL, NULL) #2
>    /home/path/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(276):
>    __TwigTemplate_febbcd3e9843c1ef02ee591d59cfb1afd51eb5cd52af42e38573c035f7ef4128-doDisplay(Array,
>    Array) #3
>    /home/path/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(250):
>    Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) #4
>    /home/path/domain in
>    /home/path/domain.com/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php on line
>    291

Comment: Silex use a controller to associate an url with a view. If you ask for the url `/robots.txt` but you don't create a controller for `robots.txt`, you can't access it. If you really want to access it with an URL, just create a controller like `$app->get('/robot') ...` and the view will just be `robots.txt`

Answer (score 0):

When you say root folder, do you mean the public_html folder, or the folder that contains folders like 'templates' and 'src'?

The large php error after "No route found for 'GET /robot.txt'" is actually being thrown when Silex is attempting to process a template document. I'm guessing the error template(s) in your silex install aren't set up correctly.

If your robots.txt file is in your publicly accessible foilder you don't need a Silex controller to serve it, but you do need the webserver to be configured to serve real files before it tries passing the request to index.php.

There are exmaple configs here https://silex.symfony.com/index.php/doc/2.0/web_servers.html

For apache the relevant bit is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

For nginx the relevant bit is

```
try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
```

These are the parts of the config that say 'check if there's actually a file for this url, and use index.php if there isn't'

Comment: yes its Public_html folder . and earlier it was working file. but not its giving error. even unable to access APIs folder. but whole site is working fine( i think) . I added those 2 lines in .htaccess files still its giving same error. 

[code]RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA][code]

Comment: even my api path which was working fine stopped working. 
Example.com/api/v1 giving similar error. 
i really need help :(